# unexpected behavior of for loop

Tags: r

I have this data table named data.txt

```
 2001  109428
2002    117034
2003    147405
2004    142642
2005    148161
2006    145700
2007    125617
2008    139669
2009    90575
2010    111989
2011    126130
2012    111258
2013    103455
2014    106235
2015    108819
2016    119000
2017    21908
```

and I want to put them in a set, being the first column is the year, and the second is number of cars that are registered that year. I used a for loop and rep() function to do this

```
carAge<- read.table('data.txt',header=FALSE)
for (i in 1:17){
set <- rep(carAge[i,1],carAge[i,2])
}
print(mean(set))
```

and the result I got is

```
[1] 2017
```

it seems like it only read the 17th line of my table, how can I resolve this? shouldn't the for-loop concatenate all the line from 1 to 17 into my number set?

Comment: you are overwriting `set` each time you loop, try appending set like this `set <- c(set, rep(carAge[i,1],carAge[i,2]))`

Comment: it works, thank you! I don't know how to give you an upvote or similar credits so if you want to please tell me.